# A direct proof for an integral condition

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, integration, matrices, analysis

Let $G(z)$ be an $n\times m$ matrix-valued rational function of full column rank on the unit circle. Let $Y$ be an $n\times n$ Hermitian (constant) matrix. Consider the following integral condition
$$\tag{1}\label{eq:cond1}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  G(e^{i\theta})G(e^{i\theta})^*YG(e^{i\theta})G(e^{i\theta})^* \mathrm{d}\theta=0,
$$
where $(\cdot)^*$ denotes Hermitian transposition.
Condition \eqref{eq:cond1} implies that $G(e^{i\theta})^*YG(e^{i\theta})\equiv 0$. This follows from the fact that \eqref{eq:cond1} is equivalent to 
$$\tag{2}\label{eq:cond2}
\mathrm{tr}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}  G(e^{i\theta})^*XG(e^{i\theta})G(e^{i\theta})^*YG(e^{i\theta}) \mathrm{d}\theta=0, \quad \forall X \in \mathcal{H}_n,
$$
where  $\mathcal{H}_n$ denotes the space of $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices and $\mathrm{tr}$ denotes trace operator, and by picking $X=Y$ in \eqref{eq:cond2}, we readily conclude.

Now, my question.

> Is it possible to conclude that $G(e^{i\theta})^*YG(e^{i\theta})\equiv 0$ ***directly*** from \eqref{eq:cond1} (i.e., without using \eqref{eq:cond2})?